# How can I create isochrones in postgis/osm2po/pgrouting and then save the isochrones as polygons?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, polygon-creation, osm2po, isochrone

I am creating some isochrones in pgrouting based upon a table from `osm2po`. Now I have a query that will get all of the edges that are `c` driving distance away from a point. How can I save this query or these individual isochrones into a table of polygons?

Perhaps a little background might help: I want to show how the isochrones change over time as different events occur or as event intensities change. So I wanted to be able to create a video that shows how the contours of the isochrones changes over time. Hence I need to create a table that has each isochrone polygon, as well as a timestamp for the date.

Any help you can provide in converting the isochrones into polygons — hopefully in PostGIS — is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join the geometry column from the original edge table which holds the geometry column. Your query will look like this:

```
SELECT t1.seq, t1.id1 AS Node, t1.id2 AS Edge, t1.cost, t2.geometry FROM PGR_DrivingDistance(
  'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM edge_table',
  1, 10, false, false) t1, edge_table t2
WHERE t1.id2 = t2.edge_id
```

If you want the Nodes instead of the Edges then just refer to the vertex table's geometry column like this:

```
SELECT t1.seq, t1.id1 AS Node, t1.id2 AS Edge, t1.cost, t2.geometry FROM PGR_DrivingDistance(
  'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM edge_table',
  1, 10, false, false) t1, edge_vertex_table t2
WHERE t1.id2 = t2.vertex_id
```

Comment: This one works as well :).

Answer (score 2):

As I remember isochrone is not a set of roads reachable in certain time, but polygon containing all of that roads, so in this case you have to get familiar with two functions: 
[ST_ConvexHull](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html) and [ST_ConcaveHull](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html). First is like placing something in a rubber baloon, second is like apply suction to this baloon.

To store it in the table of isochrones you have to do sth like (written ad-hoc so might not work as is):

```
insert into isochrones_table (start_edge, version, geom)
values
1234,
1,
(SELECT ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(geom_way),<<concave>>,false) 
FROM edges 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM pgr_drivingdistance('SELECT id, source, target, cost AS cost from edges', 1234, <<c_time>>, false, false)) 
AS route 
ON edges.source = route.id1)
```

concave is the target percent of concave - 0.7 is good compromise of quality and performace
c_time is the time of isochrone (as you probably already know)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help dude. I really appreciate your taking the time to answer all of these questions I keep posting. I am getting much more comfortable with pgrouting and postgis now, thanks to your answers.

Comment: No problem - I was at the same boat few months ago so i know that pg_routing without any help could be 'little confusing'.